# will facebook pixels see our cookies?

Tags: samesite

The specific case we are trying to figure out is what is shared with facebook (and other "first party and "third party" scripts).  FB is a pixel image using GET, currently with the url [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com).  Are our cookies set on the sites main domain (.mysite.com) or subdomain ([www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)) shared with facebook?

If we now change facebook to use a first party url, e.g. facebook.mysite.com, are our cookies set on the domain [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) and .mysite.com shared, with or without samesite set (most of our cookies dont have this set) now shared with FB?

What would really help if if someone could supply is a super simple table of examples (as per below)

Assume using GET to pull in an external resource (e.g. image, xhr request or js library), and consider the three cases where `SameSite` has value `None`, `Lax`, and `Strict`.

| origin | cookie domain | link | cookie shared? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `www.mysite.com` | `.mysite.com` | `pixel.facebook.com` | ? |
| `www.mysite.com` | `www.mysite.com` | `pixel.facebook.com` | ? |
| `www.mysite.com` | `www.mysite.com` | `pixel.mysite.com` | ? |
| `www.mysite.com` | `.mysite.com` | `pixel.mysite.com` | ? |

Comment: Voters to close: this question is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the scheme and (possibly implicit) port, not just the host, are components of a [Web origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin). Only taking the host into consideration is misleading. Therefore, I've taken the liberty to add a `https` scheme to all your examples (which has the added benefit of sidestepping a discussion about the `Secure` attribute).

Under the assumption that `example.com` be an [eTLD+1](https://web.dev/same-site-same-origin/#site), the answer doesn't depend on the value of the cookie's `SameSite` attribute in any of your four cases.

| origin | cookie domain | link | cookie shared? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `https://www.example.com` | `.example.com` | `https://pixel.facebook.com` | ❌ |
| `https://www.example.com` | `www.example.com` | `https://pixel.facebook.com` | ❌ |
| `https://www.example.com` | `www.example.com` | `https://pixel.example.com` | ❌ |
| `https://www.example.com` | `.example.com` | `https://pixel.example.com` | ✅ |

In the first three cases, browsers will not attach such a cookie to such requests.
Why? Because, in all three cases, the request host does not [*domain-match*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/#section-5.1.3) the cookie's domain attribute; see [RFC6265bis, section 5.6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis/#section-5.6), step 10 of the storage-model algorithm. In particular, cookies associated to `example.com` in someone's browser are never sent to or accessible by `facebook.com` or any subdomain thereof. However, if `example.com` loads `facebook.com` in an iframe, Facebook can use that to create cookies associated to `facebook.com`, which will then be attached to requests to Facebook.

In the fourth case, under the assumption that `example.com` be an eTLD+1, browsers will unconditionally attach such a cookie to such a request. Why? Because, in that case,

- the request host does *domain-match* the cookie's domain attribute, and
- the request is [*same-site*](https://web.dev/same-site-same-origin/), and the `SameSite` cookie attribute only has an effect on *cross-site* requests; more about this subtlety in [one of my blog posts](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2021-01-29-great-samesite-confusion/).

---

Here is a case where the value of the `SameSite` attribute *would* matter, because the request in question is *cross-site*:

| origin | cookie domain | link | SameSite | cookie shared? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `https://facebook.com` | `www.example.com` | `https://www.example.com` | None | ✅ |
| `https://facebook.com` | `www.example.com` | `https://www.example.com` | Lax | ? |
| `https://facebook.com` | `www.example.com` | `https://www.example.com` | Strict | ❌ |

In the `SameSite=None` case, browsers would unconditionally attach the cookie.

In the `SameSite=Lax` case, browsers would only attach the cookie if the request is a top-level navigation. See [Lax allowing unsafe](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-10#section-5.4.7.2), though.

In the `SameSite=Strict` case, browsers would not attach the cookie, period.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks.  The most surprising thing is that same site does not affect any of these scenarios, as for me, it would apply to the last two in some way.  If cookies are not shared to different origins/sites by default, why was samesite needed at all, as it would prevent XSS?

Comment: @JohnLittle Just to clarify: in your question, the "origin" column means the Web origin where the request was issued, correct?

Comment: Yes, www.example.com is our website, which, whilst loading the page, makes requests (xhr, img, js scripts etc) to external sources, which happens to include facebook.  Im not referring to clicking on anything, or user navigating, just page loading.

Comment: @JohnLittle Ok, see my latest addition.

Comment: your same site table is very interesting, its saying that if you click on a link to our site from any source (e.g. an ad banner), then the resultant page which gets loaded will have access to the session cookie, which means by default XSS attacks would work.  This implies we should be setting samesite=strict on our session cookies which can be used to spoof the logged in user.   could you give an example of toplevel navigation vs non top level nativation?

Comment: @JohnLittle You write: _the resultant page which gets loaded will have access to the session cookie_. No, that's not what my table is saying. The "cookie shared" column should really be renamed "cookie attached". In no way would `facebook.com` have access to cookies associated to your site. Does that clarify things for you?